# How do I add a comma after full names in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, join, split

I have a paragraph of 150 first and last names. I want to separate each full name by a comma in the array. How would i do this? Here is what I have. Please show me how to put a comma after each full name.

```js
var names= $('#namesList').html();
var nameArr = names.split(' ');
//join comma after each full name
console.log(nameArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='namesList'>Bhittersweet Angel
    Pam Hankins
    Josh Dena 
    Joanne Deutch 
    Melanie Dodd 
    Randy Scott 
    Bryan Jellick
</p>
```

Comment: This could use a language tag.  I'm assuming JavaScript.

Comment: When you split, you have a space between the first and last name, so your array will not contain full names at all.  Try using _ instead of space between the first and last, then replace '_' with ' ' after splitting.

Comment: Also you need to format your html code to the `p` element contains the exact text that expect to have. If it can vary then you need to include that in your question. See the snippet I put in place in your question, this makes it easier for others to answer your question but the sample data must be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = $('#namesList').html();
var nameArr = names.trim().split('\n').map((x) => x.trim()).join(', ');
console.log(nameArr);
```

1. The HTML of the name list is trimmed to remove excess newlines: `trim()`
2. The result is split into an array by newlines: `split('\n')`
3. Using `map`, each element of the array is trimmed to remove leading spaces
4. The final array is joined into a single string, separating elements by commas: `join(', ')`

Comment: Right you are: comments added.